# Mysql: Search in fields with space separated values

Tags: mysql

I need to build query, which will show only rows not containing specified status.

Every row has column called "status" with space separated values. For example: "Pay req. sent"
And I need to find rows without "sent" status. 
How will look optimal query in database with more than 5 000 000 rows?

Comment: Does 'sent' always come at the end?

Comment: Yes. It should come at the end

Comment: So you want all statuses not like '% sent'? Note however that this cannot use an index! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the rows you want you can do something like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE concat(' ',status,' ') not like '% sent %'
```

If status always appears at the end of the field and is always prefixed by a space

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE status not like '% sent'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use find in set:-

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('sent', REPLACE(status, ' ', ',')) > 0
```

But long term change the database design to split the status field onto another table, with one row per status.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM from_table t
WHERE t.status not like '%sent'
```